# Flash AS 2, Stacking items in the players inventory

Tags: flash, stack, actionscript-2, inventory

I have an inventory with names, and now I would like numbers with the names that increase as more of the same items are added.

*Item Code:*

```
_root.player_inventory = new Array(_root.array);

for (a = 0; a < _root.invslots; a++)
{
    _root.player_inventory[a] = "none";
}
```

*Stacking Code:*

```
_root.player_inventory[a] = new Array(_root.stackAmount);

for (b = 0; b < _root.stackAmount; b++)
{   
    _root.player_inventory[b] = 0;
    //player_inventory[a][b] = "[" + a + "][" + b + "]"; 

    //mainArrayTxt = "[" + a + "][" + b + "]"; 
    //b = 0;
}
```

My item code is fine; I would just like to add stacking to it.

[image]

I got the code from this tutorial: http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/448642

Comment: Your code just shows some default declaration/value assigning for the two arrays. Every entry is "none",0. How do players add to their inventory, do you have a function for that? Or are you looking for a way to set some default values for the player to start with?

Comment: im just looking for a way to set some default values for the players inventory stacks to start with and perhaps add to that number when a new item is added. i can give you more code if you need it. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is:

Item Code:

```
_root.default_items = ["Food","Torch","Sword","Map","Hatchet"];

_root.player_inventory = new Array(_root.array);

for (a = 0; a < _root.invslots; a++)
//fill all inventory spots with "none"
{
    _root.player_inventory[a] = "none";

}

for (a = 0; a < _root.default_items; a++)
//set first spots to default items
{
    _root.player_inventory[a] = _root.default_items[a];
}
```

Stacking Code:

```
_root.default_stack = [10,1,1,1,1];

for (b = 0; b < _root.player_inventory; b++)
//set the amount to default stack or 0
{   
    if(_root.player_inventory[b] != "none")
    {
       _root,player_inventory[b].push(_root.default_stack[b]);
    } else {
       _root,player_inventory[b].push(0);
    }

}
```

In the end your _root.player_inventory Array will have values like:

```
_root.player_inventory[0][0] returns Food
_root.player_inventory[0][1] returns 10
```

Unfortunately I can't test the code bcause my Flash version is too old, but this is the general idea.